# Configure list of java class objects through yaml

Tags: java, yaml, dropwizard

I am using the dropwizard framework which uses Yaml for configuration.I wanted to specify class names in the config file.Is there a way in which Yaml will parse it to Class objects or do I have to do it using Strings ?

```
class Config {

  .........

  List<Class<?> resourceClasses;    
} 

YAML file

#resource classes
resourceClasses : 
       - com.abc.StoresResource
       - com.abc.MerchantResource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for a convenient way to register your resources or do you really want to configure the resources in the YAML configuration? If it's the former this is what I'd do:

```java
for (ClassInfo classInfo: ClassPath.from(getClass().getClassLoader()).getTopLevelClasses("com.abc")) {
  environment.jersey().register(i.getInstance(classInfo.load()));
}
```

If it's the latter you'd have to parse those strings yourself. I don't think that the YAML configuration will do that for you. Would something like this work:

```java
class Config {
  List<Class<?>> resourceClasses = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

  @JsonProperty("resourceClasses")
  public void setResourceClasses(Collection<String> classNames) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    for (String className : classNames) {
      resourceClasses.add(Class.forName(className));
    }
  }     

}
```

Comment: I want to declaratively apply our company's transaction logging framework on certain resource classes.So it is the latter

Comment: Added an example of the latter - see if that works for your purpose.